# Best way to call methods of child objects in a list?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a system of GUI elements that all inherit a base class. I want to be able to call all of the child elements by calling a Draw method in the parent class. Here is essentially what I have so far:

Base element:

```
interface GuiElementBase
{
protected:
    std::vector<GuiElementBase> children;
public: 
    void Draw()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
            children[i].Draw();
    }
    void AddChild(GuiElementBase child)
    {
        children.push_back(child);
    }
};
```

Text element:

```
class GuiElementText : public GuiElementBase
{
public:
    void Draw()
    {
        GuiElementBase::Draw();
        // + some text-specific drawing code
    }
};
```

Implementation:

```
GuiElementText* TextTest;

void GUI::Init()
{
    TextTest = new GuiElementText();
    TextTest->AddChild(GuiElementText());
}

void GUI::Draw()
{
    TextTest->Draw();
}
```

Constructors, drawing code, and other methods were left out for simplicity's sake.

When it tries to update the TextTest child, it obviously just calls GuiElementBase::Draw() because the "children" vector is GuiElementBase. I have been having trouble finding a way to have it call the child object and not the base class. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `interface`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad a struct

Comment: You should use a pure abstract class instead of a macro or whatever it is.

Comment: Make `Draw` virtual?

Comment: Anyway, you need to use an `std::vector<std::uniqe_ptr<base>>` or something similar. You cannot perform virtual dispatch through a value, you need a pointer or reference, and you cannot have a vector of references

Comment: @AluanHaddad `std::reference_wrapper` is an option.

Comment: You need to understand how virtual methods work. You also need to understand what is object slicing and why, as designed, what you have will not work. That's why you've been "having trouble finding a way" to make this work, because, fundamentally, as designed, this cannot possibly work due to object slicing.

Comment: `virtual void Draw();`

Comment: @cantordust interesting.

Comment: @cantordust Maybe if the lifetime of the objects is otherwise managed, but more often you want the container to own the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example, the base Draw() is executed first then Draw() for each child in vector. Is this what you are after?

```
#include <iostream>

class GuiElementBase
{
private:
    std::vector<GuiElementBase *> children;
public:
    virtual void Draw()
    {
        std::cout << "GuiElementBase draw" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
            children[i]->Draw();
    }
    void AddChild(GuiElementBase *child)
    {
        children.push_back(child);
    }
};

class GuiElementText : public GuiElementBase
{
public:
    void Draw() override
    {
        std::cout << "GuiElementText draw" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    GuiElementBase base;
    GuiElementText* child = new GuiElementText();

    base.AddChild(child);
    base.AddChild(child);

    base.Draw();

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
GuiElementBase draw
GuiElementText draw
GuiElementText draw
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why I completely forgot virtual functions existed. Thanks.